# LangChain Zero Shot React Agent uses memory or not?

Tags: python, langchain, large-language-model, py-langchain

I'm experimenting with LangChain's `AgentType.CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT` agent. By its name I'd assume this is an agent intended for chat use and I've given it memory but it doesn't seem able to access its memory. What else do I need to do so that this will access its memory? Or have I incorrectly assumed that this agent can handle chats?

Here is my code and sample output:

```py
llm = ChatOpenAI(model_name="gpt-4",
                 temperature=0)

tools = load_tools(["llm-math", "wolfram-alpha", "wikipedia"], llm=llm)
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")

agent_test = initialize_agent(
    tools=tools, 
    llm=llm, 
    agent=AgentType.CHAT_ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION, 
    handle_parsing_errors=True,
    memory=memory, 
    verbose=True
)
```

```
>>> agent_test.run("What is the height of the empire state building?")
'The Empire State Building stands a total of 1,454 feet tall, including its antenna.'
>>> agent_test.run("What was the last question I asked?")
"I'm sorry, but I can't provide the information you're looking for."
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not. that's indicated by `zero-shot` which means just look at the current prompt. [from here](https://www.pinecone.io/learn/series/langchain/langchain-agents/)

> Zero-shot means the agent functions on the current action only — it
> has no memory. It uses the ReAct framework to decide which tool to
> use, based solely on the tool’s description.

I think when you work with this agent type, you should add `description` to the tool. so that based on the description, llm will infer which tool used. that is the `description` part of ""zero-shot-react-description". example from same link above:

```
math_tool = Tool(
    name='Calculator',
    func=llm_math.run,
    description='Useful for when you need to answer questions about math.'
)
```

When the llm sees the prompt, if it infers that prompt is related to math, it will use the `math_tool`

If you want to use memory, you should be using [chat-conversational-react-description](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/agents/agent_types/chat_conversation_agent)

```
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory
from langchain.chat_models import ChatOpenAI

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history", return_messages=True)
llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, temperature=0)
agent_chain = initialize_agent(tools, llm, agent=AgentType.CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION, verbose=True, memory=memory)
```

Comment: So the fact that the agent has a `memory` attribute is just left over from its parent class?

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 key prefixes to consider when working with LangChain's agents: `ZERO_SHOT`, `CHAT`, and `CONVERSATIONAL`.

If your goal is to engage in a conversation with an agent that utilizes chat history, you should opt for agents with the `CONVERSATIONAL` prefix, such as `CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION` or `CHAT_CONVERSATIONAL_REACT_DESCRIPTION`.

Now, what does the `CHAT` prefix mean? Contrary to what you might expect, it doesn't imply conversations, instead, it indicates the underlying prompt generation/model being used. In the context of language models, there are primarily two types: **base models** like GPT and **chat models** like ChatGPT.

- **Base models** are trained to complete sentences by predicting the next word. For example:

```
Input: The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy ___
Output: dog
```

- On the other hand, **chat models** are fine-tuned versions of base models specifically designed for conversational interactions with users. They can handle zero-shot interactions or multiple rounds of interactions (CONVERSATIONAL).

This distinction helps you choose the right agent based on your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

LangChain docs demonstrate the use of memory with a ZeroShot agent as well.
See [this](https://python.langchain.com/docs/modules/memory/agent_with_memory).

What I'm unsure about is how adding memory benefits agents or chat models if the entire message history along with `intermediate_steps` is passed via `{agent_scratchpad}` in the subsequent prompt. Also, both of them anyway increase the number of tokens to be processed in the next call.